# Make sure teams create items in their own area

Tags: azure-devops

I was wondering how it could be possible to make sure people from one team can only create work items related to their area?

Is it possible to force it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [security groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-permissions-access-work-tracking?view=azure-devops#create-child-nodes-modify-work-items-under-an-area-path) to limit teams to the areas they should have access to create work items under.